# Does a healing spell after Beacon of Hope deal maximum healing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Beacon of Hope is a concentration spell. Say a cleric casts it one turn and then decides to use Cure Wounds on their next turn. Cure Wounds would break concentration on the spell, thereby ending Beacon of Hope. The question is, does the spell lose its effects BEFORE or AFTER the effects of the new spell take place?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Cure Wounds* does not break concentration.

> The following factors can
>   break concentration:
>
> • Casting another spell that requires concentration.
>   You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another
>   spell that requires concentration. You can’t concentrate
>   on two spells at once.
>
> • Taking damage. [...]
>
> • Being incapacitated or killed. [...]

If *Cure Wounds* required concentration, than casting it would break your concentration on *Beacon of Hope*. However, since *Cure Wounds* does not break concentration, *Beacon of Hope* will still apply when you cast *Cure Wounds*, and *Cure Wounds* will heal the maximum amount.

The more general question here is "If, while concentrating on a spell, you cast another spell that requires concentration, will the first spell lose its effects BEFORE or AFTER the effects of the new spell take place?"

The answer to that is that the effects of the first spell will end before any effects of the new spell apply. This is because concentration is ended by:

> Casting another spell that requires concentration.

The moment you're casting another spell that requires concentration, your concentration on the first spell is ended.